# NavigationMixin.Navigate - standard__webPage in Community Site -

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {
            url: 'https://wwww.salesforce.com'
        }
```

Its not working in community site. How do I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

In the [Summer '19 release](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_lwc_modules.htm), Salesforce enhanced the support of lightning-navigation in Community with `comm__namedPage` (instead of `standard__namedPage`), `pageReferences` and `state`.

```
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            pageName: 'https://wwww.salesforce.com'
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much . It worked.